# Error in retrieving and binding to a datagridview from a mysql stored procedure with concat()

Tags: .net, mysql, datagridview

Everytime i retrieve data from a mysql stored procedure with a concat function an error will occur after binding the datagridview to the datatable that holds the returned rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should make an alias for selected value:

```
select concat(column1, column2) as concatenated from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

`select CAST(concat(column1, column2)AS CHAR)` as concatenated from table1